# UIView Frame issues Based on Direction

Tags: ios

I have Placing Buttons on UIView SubClass, were Height is Dynamic based on Buttons Count and width. When i add Button to View, Then based on Buttons the RKBaseView height is increased . iam increasing the VSBaseView Height based on Button Height. But height is increased in Down Direction . so what i need is the View has to Increase in upward direction. please check the below link for [sample link](https://copy.com/TEO6bjdvMJvo)

Answer (score 0):

In VSBaseView.m replace

```
selfFrame.origin.y = self.frame.origin.y - diffHeight.size.height;
```

with

```
selfFrame.origin.y = 200 - selfFrame.size.height;
```

i hope it helps :)